# lengthy resume from hibernate ubuntu 20.04LTS on Gateway E-475M laptop

Tags: suspend, hibernate

Running Ubuntu 20.04LTS on Gateway e-475M laptop with 2Gb RAM/4Gb SWAP.

Got hibernate (to disk), and suspend (to RAM), to work on it (finally) and hibernates fine *(Except wifi pci driver gets corrupted using suspend - I use usb wifi as alternate; On hibernate the pci wifi driver will get corrupted if I don't manually switch off wifi using laptop button before hibernating, then leave off during resume until desktop 'stabilized' then switch on, and select network... wifi had to be set to manually connect, not auto or corruption guaranteed!)*

Anyhoo, enough about the quirks of Ubuntu 20.04LTS and my pci wifi driver ~ upon resuming from hibernation, the desktop is totally 'frozen' for a few minutes (mouse won't move, keyboard dead, etc.), then things begin to 'thaw' very slowly like browser, terminal, etc. unresponsive for about 15 to 20 minutes, then all is fine. Totally unusable requiring me to use shutoff not hibernate, or go thru circus act every morning. Shutoff loses place in my freecell game so not really solution.

What makes it so locked up upon resuming from hibernation, only to finally be usable after 15-20 minutes of leaving it alone? Resumes from suspend within seconds...

This clown car is forcing me to use the win7 dual boot as default - win7 suspends/hibernates fine w/o freezing or corruption, and lets me read my online paper without all the wait, plus leaves my freecell game waiting on me ;-)

---

Everything works fine - great even! ... **UNTIL** in and out of hibernation/suspend then ubuntu goes out to lunch for a bit, then after a fashion, everything works fine again - great also ~ RAM? install media? graphics card? maybe even gremlins, for real? ... and win7 does a better job of utilizing RAM so hibernate/suspend works w/o bugs, freezing, etc.?

ran:
$ inxi -G
Command 'inxi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install inxi
... any other way to find driver besides installing something Ubuntu 20.04LTS doesn't come with?

btw - using a keyboard shortcut "super + H" to run command: 'systemctl hibernate' in order to hibernate... important?

Well, shut down laptop completely, rebooted into ubuntu 20.04LTS, loaded quick and great, did not launch anything at all ~ then hit hibernate, and upon resume it is frozen, takes forever to thaw, etc. .....................so, still problem with RAM?

ATI graphics??? Settings => About => Graphics => sez "Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics (primary)", not some ATI thingy... so, what?

Comment: Looking at the specs it seems you've got an ATI graphics card (sth. you should've mentioned) - my educated guess (therefore comment and not answer) is, that the ATI driver doesn't work properly. The only card I'ver ever got in and out of hibernation on a laptop was Intel. Please add the driver from `inxi -G` and paste it into your answer by using the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1361934/edit) link.

Comment: System Requirements for Ubuntu 20.04
2 GHz dual-core processor.
4 GiB RAM (but 1 GiB can work)
25 GB of hard-drive space.
VGA capable of 1024×768 screen resolution.
Either of the two: a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media.
Optionally, Internet access is helpful. Your machine does not have enough ram.

Comment: There are plenty of instances in this forum regarding dual boot issues and sleep/suspend.  You can always search this forum for those issues and see if anything resolves it.  But I felt the same way, that the programs and services that running are competing for resources causing them to run slow until they complete.  Which is related to RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so nothing to do with what media was used when ubuntu was installed, nothing to do with RAM, nothing to do with video driver, nothing to do with other 'guesses', etc.

The key to this mystery should've been seen by the most knowledgeable where this info was provided: *"...wifi had to be set to manually connect, not auto..."*

Seems the system goes into panic when it boots up if there is no internet connection (not automatically connected), and so the bloody thing just stalls everything until it gets its way... then, just finally gives up after 15 to 20 minutes and lets things continue without the internet.

**ALL I DID** was reset both the wifi's to connect automatically, and behold - it boots up quickly outta hibernation. ***That's all it was!***

**ON A SIDE NOTE**: The PCI wifi seems to not get corrupted anymore after resuming... some ubuntu update must've **FINALLY** fixed the problem with the “iwl3945” PCI wifi driver that my intel/pro wireless 3945ABG PCI wifi device uses which does not support hardware scanning very well, however it is a default behavior that Network-Manager expects.

I had nothing to lose while diagnosing this "*resume from hibernation slow-down issue*" so I reset it from manual to auto just to try something - anything - and discovered no more hibernate resume problem - which the slow-down incidentally seemed to have come up about the time I was trying to fix the wifi corruption issue... have to see if wifi still gets corrupted resuming outta suspend - let ya know ;-)

Comment: PCI wifi still gets corrupted coming out of suspend (disappears completely), but usb wifi still online and works fine... at lease hibernate no longer corrupts the PCI wifi for some reason... small victories!

Comment: Adjusted my 'swappiness' from 60 to 80 and it seems to help (using 2Gb RAM / 4Gb SWAP...)